# React - Construct a numeric array for a component to a dynamic number

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I need to provide a sub component with an array of numbers from state - the array is defined by a provided total number (this.props.totalMarkerNumbers) prop (in string format) - i'm going astray with the syntax construct and wonder if anyone can please point me in the correct direction please?

Heres my code to create the array:

```
const ArrayCont = () => {
  let i = 0;
  let totalM = parseInt(this.props.totalMarkerNumbers, 10);
  for (i = 0; i < totalM.length; i++) {
    let no="''" + i +"''";
    return(
      {
        label:no,
        value:no
      }
    )
  }
}
const Markers = () => {

  let arrayCont = 
  return (
    [{this.ArrayCont}]
  )
}
```

This would be stored in state as:

```
class A_Log extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      
      markerArray:Markers,
    };
  }
```

basically if this.props.totalMarkerNumbersprovided **'4'** i'd want the array to be:

```
this.state.markerArray = [
  {
    label: '1',
    value: '1',
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    value: '2',
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    value: '3',
  },
  {
    label: '4',
    value: '4',
  },
];
```

theres probably a lot easier way to achieve this - any advice very welcome!  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 main issue in your code:

The first is this line:

```
let no="''" + i +"''";
```

I suppose you're trying to convert your int into a string, but it's not the correct way, you should instead use the [toString function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)

The second is the return of your ArrayCont function.
With the provided code, you'll return an object containing one label and one value.
If you want to return an array, you have to create one and fill it each time you go through your loop

Here is a basic example:

```
function ArrayCont() {
  let arraySize = parseInt(this.props.totalMarkerNumbers, 10);
  const result = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= arraySize; i++) {
    result.push({
      label: i.toString(),
      value: i.toString(),
    });
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to using a functional react component? Something like this does the trick:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {

  const [ inputVal, setInputVal ] = useState('0');

  const [ myArray, setMyArray ] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let val = e.currentTarget.value          // get input value
    setInputVal(val);                        // set it to state
    let newArray = [];                       // build a new array
    for (let i = 0; i < val; i++) {          // for each between 0-val...
      newArray.push({                            // push obj to array
        label: i + 1,
        value: i + 1,
      })
    };
    setMyArray(newArray);                    // set the array to state
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input 
        value={inputVal}
        onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <p>
          {JSON.stringify(myArray)}
        </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

I reread your question and see if that you are interested in knowing how to pass props. So I've reworked my above example to show how you might ingest a string from an input, and use that to build (and show) your array.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

/**
 * EgChildComponent -- Function
 * An example of how to pass state to a child component
 * @param {number} inputVal The value of the input.
 * @return {JSX.Element} A list of styled paragraph with your content
 */
const EgChildComponent = ({ inputVal }) => {
  
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);

  const updateArray = useCallback((val) => {
    let newArray = []; // build a new array
    for (let i = 0; i < val; i++) {
      // for each between 0-val...
      newArray.push({
        // push obj to array
        label: i + 1,
        value: i + 1
      });
    }
    setMyArray(newArray); // set the array to state
  }, [setMyArray]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myArray.length.toString() !== inputVal) {
      updateArray(inputVal)
    }
  }, [inputVal, myArray.length, updateArray]);

  const aChild = (childItem) => {
    return (
      <p key={`child-${JSON.stringify(childItem)}`}>
        <b>Label: {childItem.label}</b>, value: {childItem.value}
      </p>
    );
  };

  return <>{myArray.map((item) => aChild(item))}</>;
};


/**
 * Parent component where the value is set, and passed
 * to the child via props, which then dynamically updates
 * the array as desired.
 */
export default function App() {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let val = e.currentTarget.value; // get input value
    setInputVal(val); // set it to state
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={inputVal} onChange={handleChange} />
      {inputVal !== '' && (
        <EgChildComponent inputVal={inputVal} /> 
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-66696633-updatedarray-vm3rm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you right, but I guess this?

```js
const getArr = (x) => Array.from(Array(+x),(_,i)=>({label:String(i+1),value:String(i+1)}))
console.log('Total markers 3:');
console.log(getArr('3'));
console.log('Total markers 5:');
console.log(getArr('5'));
console.log('Total markers 10:');
console.log(getArr('10'));
```